# DD-WRT Build Kills Postfix Rewrite

Tags: postfix-mta, dd-wrt

Okay, this one is a head scratcher. Some background -- I have been running an old DD-WRT Kong build (8-June-2019) on my Netgear R7000 router for almost a year. I recently upgraded it to the latest BrainSlayer build and everything seemed fine, except for one thing. For over ten years, on a variety of routers, I have been using Postfix masquerade to rewrite the 'from' address on email that gets generated by scripts on my local domain on my MacBook Pro so that SMTP relay servers will see a legitimate email address. When I'm behind the new DD-WRT build, the emails are bounced back because the rewrite doesn't seem to occur and the SMTP relay is seeing a local domain address. I have since switched back to my old DD-WRT Kong build and Postfix masquerade is working again.

What could be going on with the new build that prevents Postfix rewrite from occurring? I am using the default firewall settings on both builds and all the other settings match. I'm baffled.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm a doofus -- I power-cycled my cable modem after trying the latest DD-WRT build again and this is now working. I usually don't do that after an upgrade, but now it will be the first thing that I do when I hit an issue. :-)

UPDATE -- never mind, the power-cycle fix is only temporary. I'm back on the old build.